# Changing route from Vuex actions and components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

After a user has successfully logged into my app via a login form. I want to check if they have a profile. If they **do** I want to send them to News page. If they **don't** have one set, I want it to redirect them to the Settings page. How would I do this using Vuex?

I guess there are a few options:

### 1. Components responsible for the redirects? (doesn't feel right)

Login.vue

```
handleFormSubmit () {
this.$store.dispatch('loginFormSubmit', formData)
    .then(() => {
      // This feels a bit gross
      this.$store.dispatch('getUserProfile')
        .then(() => this.$router.push('/news'))
        .catch(() => this.$router.push('/settings'))
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.loginError = true
    })
}
```

### 2. Would I keep the responsibility in the actions?

user-actions.js

```
export const getUserProfile = ({commit}) => {
  commit(types.USER_PROFILE_REQUEST)
  const options = {
    url: `${API_URL}/profile`,
    method: 'GET'
  }

  return request(options)
    .then((profileSettings) => {
      // Would I change the router to News here??

      commit(types.USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS, profileSettings)
      return Promise.resolve(profileSettings)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Would I change the router to Settings here??

      commit(types.UI_MENU_HIDE)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
}

export const loginFormSubmit = ({dispatch, commit}, { email, password }) => {
  console.log(email, password)
  commit(types.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST)
  const options = {
    url: `${API_URL}/token`
  }
  return request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch('getUserProfile')
      commit(types.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, response.token)
      return Promise.resolve(response.token)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      commit(types.USER_LOGIN_FAILURE, error)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
}
```

### 3. Maybe it should be kept in the router with guards?

Login.vue

```
handleFormSubmit () {
this.$store.dispatch('loginFormSubmit', formData)
    .then(() => this.$router.push('/news'))
    .catch(() => {
      this.loginError = true
    })
}
```

Then in my router:

```
const routes = [
      {
        path: 'news',
        alias: '',
        component: NewsView,
        name: 'News',
        meta: { description: 'News feed page' },
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
          store.dispatch('getUserProfile')
-          .then((resp) => {
-            // Profile set
-            next()
-          })
-          .catch(() => {
-            // No profile set
-            next({ name: 'settings' })
-          })
        }
      },
]
```

### 4. Listen out for store change, then change route

```
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated () {
      return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
    }
  },

  watch: {
    isAuthenticated () {
      this.$router.push('/calendar')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit (formData) {
      // Updates isAuthenticated on success
      this.$store.dispatch('requestAuthToken', formData)
    }
  }
```

Maybe number three or four is best? It feels the cleanest but would love to know what you guys think :D

Thanks for taking the time in advance!

Comment: Did you found out the best approach?

Comment: I really like #4 but #3 would probably work too. I just used #4 this to solve this problem for myself, actually. Thanks for posting this. Sorry you didn't get a response. I marked this original question as a favorite.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a combination of 2 solutions for redirects/handling errors:

1. Use an `axios` interceptor for the most clear cut status codes:

   ```
   import axios from 'axios'

   axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
       const { status } = error.response
       const errorMessage = error.response.data.message

       if (status === Constants.STATUS_CODE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
           router.push('/404')
          return
       } else if (status === Constants.STATUS_CODE_ERROR_UNAUTHENTICATED){
         ...
       }
       ...
    }
   ```
2. Make the check in the action and return in the component for redirecting or other necessary operations.

On another note, please consider using `async/await` instead of `then/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a version of your idea #2. Why not something like this:

1. You call `handleFormSubmit()` in `Login.vue` which dispatches `loginFormSubmit()` action. Maybe enable a loading state in `Login.vue` at this point for UX.
2. If the user can login, you call `getUserProfile()`, else show error in `Login.vue`
3. `getUserProfile()` fetches from the API
4. You test `response` from the API either within your action or pass `response` to a seperate mutation which does that.
5. If the user has profile data, update `state` and  `router.push('/pathToNews')`, else `router.push('/pathToSettings')`

Here is simplified *psuedo-code* to illustrate the concept:

```js
// store

  state: {
    userProfile: {}
  },

  mutations: {
    setUserProfile (state, payload) {
      state.userProfile = payload
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getUserProfile() {
      let self = this
      axios.get('${API_URL}/token')
      .then(function (response) {
        // test response against what is expected for a populated profile
        if (response.data is a populated user profile) {
          self.commit('setUserProfile', response.data)
          self.router.push('/news')
        } else {
          self.router.push('/settings')
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // handle your error
      })
      .finally(function () {
        // always executed
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

my flow:

1. component 
   `(this.$store.dispatch('getProfile'...)`
2. action - server (`const response = await fetch ...`)
   commit a response to the mutation
3. mutation save info to the store
4. store (the only place contain all information)
5. component (reactively fetch data from this.$store.state.user.hasProfile and make a decision what to do )

summary: you send request {login, password}, then receive response from server something like 
    {hasProfile: true/false}

```
    if(hasProfile) {
      // router to
    } else  {
      // router to
    }
```